# The method put(String, ArrayList<Object>) in the type HashMap<String,ArrayList<Object>> is not applicable for the arguments (String, ArrayList<Burger>

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, arraylist

I am trying to put `ArrayList<Burger>` for `ArrayList<Object>` but I get this error.

I want the `ArrayList<Object>` to stay as object, how can I go about getting this done?

This is the error it gives me for thisModelInfo.put(...);

```
The method put(String, ArrayList<Object>) in the type HashMap<String,ArrayList<Object>> is not applicable for the arguments (String, ArrayList<Burger>)
```

Here is my code.

```
package com.ashgharibyan.apiofapis.controllers;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.ashgharibyan.apiofapis.models.Burger;
import com.ashgharibyan.apiofapis.models.User;
import com.ashgharibyan.apiofapis.services.BurgerService;
import com.ashgharibyan.apiofapis.services.UserService;

@RestController
public class UserAPIController {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userServ;
    
    @Autowired
    private BurgerService burgerServ;

    @RequestMapping("/api/all")
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, ArrayList<HashMap<String, ArrayList<Object>>>>> index() {
        
        
        List<User> allUsers = (List<User>) userServ.allUsers();
        
        
        
        
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, ArrayList<HashMap<String, ArrayList<Object>>>>> mainAPI =  new ArrayList<>();
        
        
        
        
        for(int i=0; i<allUsers.size();i++) {
            // One User Level
            HashMap<String, ArrayList<HashMap<String, ArrayList<Object>>>> thisUserInfo = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<HashMap<String, ArrayList<Object>>>>();

            //All Model Level
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, ArrayList<Object>>> allModelInfo = new ArrayList<>();
            
            //Current Model Level
            HashMap<String, ArrayList<Object>> thisModelInfo = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Object>>();
            
            ArrayList<Burger> allBurgers = (ArrayList<Burger>) burgerServ.allBurgers();
            
            thisModelInfo.put("burger", allBurgers);
            
            allModelInfo.add(thisModelInfo);
            
            thisUserInfo.put(allUsers.get(i).getUserName(), allModelInfo);
            
            mainAPI.add(thisUserInfo);
        }
        
        
        return mainAPI;
    }
}
```

I cannot figure out what to do to make this work. I need it to be dynamic as I will be changing the model names that I am importing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either
change `ArrayList<Burger>` to `ArrayList<Object>`
or
change

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<HashMap<String, ArrayList<Object>>>> thisUserInfo = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<HashMap<String, ArrayList<Object>>>>();
```

to

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<HashMap<String, ArrayList<Burger >>>> thisUserInfo = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<HashMap<String, ArrayList< Burger>>>>();
```